# Email Automation in Shell Script: Add an input when you run the script

Tags: shell, unix

I was able to run the script for email automation using this code:

echo 'This is a test'  | mail -s 'Test mail' test@mail.com -- -f test@mail.com

However, I would like to be able to add an additional value when I run the script i.e ./email_test.sh value—the value is a variable that I need to include on the email message body.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

body=$1

echo $body | mail -s 'Test mail' test@mail.com -- -f test@mail.com
```

then call the script as you requests `./email_test.sh value` but don't forget to make it executable using `chmod +x email_test.sh`

Update: If you need to treat the email as a variable then you need to add it as `email=$2` just like we did with `body=$1` but the email will be the second argument in this case and same goes for the subject.

Comment: I got it working, but I would like to put this value below the subject. Apparently, it doesn't read Html tags unlike Php.

Comment: body=$1


echo 'This is a test email' <br/> <br/> $body  | mail -s 'Test mail'

Comment: Thanks! how would I make the email address receiver a variable? 'mail -s 'Test mail' test@mail.com'.

Comment: I added a solution for making the email as an argument which can be passed through the command line as a second argument

Comment: I would need to put the value inside the email: 


Hello


Value


Kind Regards,

Comment: Greetings!


Hello


Value


Kind Regards,

Comment: You mean to add random email to the body itself ? What about `email='me@email.com' ; ./email_test.sh "Hello, this is a test email kind regards $email"` then this will be treated as a body which will have the value of `$email`. Note that you have to pass the argument between double quotes not single quotes

Comment: Hi I am looking to pass the 'numeric value' inside the email body message. This value is a variable which can be inputted when running the script i.e email_test 100000—the value would show inside the email body message. Thanks!

Comment: Whatever you need to add it to the body you can define it before calling the script like this:
`mailnumber=2 ;email='mostafa@example.com'; ./test_email.sh "hello blabla, this is a test email number $mailnumber. Kind regards, $email"` and the result of the body will be like this:

hello blabla, this is a test email number 2. Kind regards, mostafa@example.com

Comment: Unless the script itself will do something else before sending the email then  the numeric variable can be defined inside the script itself

Comment: Hi, this is the output was:

Comment: Greetings! $body

 This is to send more than 100 emails simultaneously

Comment: It's not returning the value of $body when inside the statement.

Comment: could you send me the the code as a gist on github or similar ?

Comment: I cannot see the link , if $body inside a text statement make sure to that your whole text is between double quotes like this "This is the email $body"

Comment: Oh ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Yes thats what i expected, Shell will never treat $body as a variable if its between single quotes. it needs to be double quotes. glad to help!

Comment: IT'S GOOD! YEAH! THANK YOU!